# openvpn create route once the tunnel is established

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I want to have access to my office LAN from my private server

I have successfully set up a VPN tunnel between my private server and my computer at my office using [this link](http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/openvpn).

I can for instance ping both my server from my computer and my computer from my server.
I use then 10.9.8.[1-2] IPs (1 for the client, 2 for the server).

Now, my office lan is in a 172.24.x.x/16 network.

I have create a route on my server side (route add -net 172.24.0.0/16 gw 10.9.8.1 (the IP of my computer at work) dev tun0
And enable the ip_forwarding on my computer at work.

However, nothing is routing when from my server I ping a random IP on my work-LAN.

Nothing in syslog and the packet is not received by my computer.

Does anyone have any clue to help me with this issue?

Many thanks for helping

Comment: Need moar info.  Perhaps OpenVPN configs, and addressing for your network.  As with most routing problems your answer can usually be find by correct using of tcpdump + traceroute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from enabling IP forwarding and setting the route to 172.24.0.0/16 on your client computer (which is done with the `push route` directive in your OpenVPN server's config), the hosts in your office LAN 172.24.0.0/16 need to know the route *back to the VPN network* 10.9.8.0/24. If you can't or don't want to change the back routes, you might resort to NAT at the OpenVPN server:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This would allow connections from your OpenVPN client to your office LAN, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. The rule `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` solved my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

To access your work-LAN from your VPN client, you'll need:

1. `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in the VPN endpoint's sysctls.
2. The VPN endpoint should be the default gateway for the work-LAN
3. `push "route 172.24.0.0/16"` must be in the server config for your VPN client to access that network from home

If the VPN endpoint is **not** the work-LAN router, it's possible to do it but it's a bit different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

1 and 3 are set up, but the VPN endpoint is not the default gateway. I have thought that the packets would go between the tun0 and the eth0 interface (thanks to net.ipv4.ip_forward=1), but obviously this is not the case.

Could you please tell me more about how to set it up, without having the VPN endpoint as the work-LAN Router?

Thanks again

Comment: In that case, the packets will get routed correctly **from** your client to the destination computer. For example, a ping will get there from your VPN client. But the reply will be sent to the default gateway and then it gets lost. Are you responsible for the default gateway?

Comment: I am not responsible for the default gateway hence I can not change it :/
However, I have set up the iptables `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` and get it working :)
Thanks for your answer